# AWS Lambda + SNS infinite loop

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

I was trying to setup an Amazon IOT button and created a lambda that has to be triggered when the button is pressed. The lambda send out an email to my account using SNS. I also added another trigger for the lambda when SNS is called. This created an infinite loop and i am getting tons of emails.
I deleted the sns topic, subscription and also the lambda. Even after that i keep getting emails. How do i stop this loop?

Comment: You probably have thousands of emails queued up and it will take a while to stop receiving them.

Comment: Thank you mark. Will wait and see if it stops.

Comment: Have it stopped yet? If so, please write an answer stating that it has stopped after waiting x time and it costed you nearly nothing or a lot of money.